# Maven Nexus: add group repository only with artifacts with prefix xxx.yyy

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus, maven-deploy-plugin

I wonder if it's possible to define a Group Repository in Maven Nexus and tell it to get the artifacts from existing repositories, but only those with ID matching a certain prefix xxx.yyy

This way, not all the artifacts of a repository will be available at this group repository, but only those I want to publish.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nexus 2.x professional, you can use procurement to define a restricted view on a repository, allowing only artifacts that fulfil certain rules. Your intended rule should be among the possible ones.